Old Asian movie about a tycoon forfeiting his wealth to save a kidnapped child
Language
I think it was Japanese, not sure though. Surely it was an asian movie and not an Indian movie.
Year 
Not sure, I remember it as a black and white movie. Definitely old. Probably in the 60s or 70s.
Plot as I remember 
The hero is a business tycoon who lives in a palace like house on top of a hill. From what I remember, he was trying to purchase 100% share of his business from his partners. His business life was at a critical stage. Just at the wrong time, someone kidnapped the son (or daughter, can't remember) of his maid. Kidnappers actually tried to kidnap his child, but by mistake took the maid's child instead. They asked for ransom, and even though it wasn't his child, the tycoon was eventually willing to give away all the money (thereby his whole business and dreams). 
One of the other characters in the movie is his secretary, who was later found out as a traitor who works for his business partners. Then there is a police inspector, who was impressed by the generosity of the business tycoon who throw away all his dreams to get his maids child back. Then there are the partners of his business firm, who were initially suspected to have done the kidnapping, since that will prevent the hero gaining full control over the business. Eventually, the kidnapper was found to be a poor man living in the village below where the tycoon lived. The reason for kidnapping was the jealousy he developed by always seeing the affluent life of the hero on the top of the hill, while he lived in the street. 
Eventually, the child was found, kidnapper was put to jail, but the hero lost all his wealth. I remember the last scene where the hero going to jail to see the kidnapper and there it is revealed to us the actual reason for kidnapping. 
There is a very touching scene near the end of the movie when the hero tries to open a jammed suitcase using some workers tools. These are the tools he used at his youth, when he was a regular worker, before he became the business tycoon . Symbolically, he is going down there again, as he is forfeiting all his business for the retrieval of the child.
These are the things I remember about the movie. I watched this around 4 years back when I was on a spree and watching classics one after another. Now I lost all my movie collections and struggling to remember the movies I watched and liked. Anyone?

Finally I was able to identify this movie. It is High and Low released in 1963 and from none other than Akira Kurosawa. Original Japanese version is Tengoku to jigoku.
The plot of this movie is there in Wikipedia which matches the plot in my question. Also I have confirmed the movie by watching the trailer in Youtube:



As I said in the question, I had a feeling that the movie is a classic. I also felt that it was Japanese, though I wasn't sure of it. I googled for "Classic Japanese Movies" and read the plot of all movies that come up in the list. I also tried to watch the trailer of each of those movies. That led me to the correct movie and it took around 90 minutes. And it saved me from a "Classic Korean movie" search as well. 

Is there any chance you can provide some more elaboration as to why this is the searched movie and in which way it fits to the details from the question?

@NapoleonWilson sorry new here. But since I am the OP of the question and I have verified the movie plot (from wikipedia) and identified it as the correct movie, is there any more explanation needed? How should I explain?

Yes, since there might be other people looking for it. We are first and foremost building an archive of interesting questions for the future, so whoever comes to this question might want to understand why this is the correct answer. Word of mouth doesn't really help so much with that. You could explain in which way this film fits to the details from the question or how you found it or how you know it's the correct answer.

@NapoleonWilson updated. Please check
